# How to check for duration on shake in android?

Tags: android, shake

I have tried this code, but it does not seem to check for shake duration effectively. I want to get a farther latitude and longitude when shake for a long time.

```
@Override public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
        ImageView colorBox = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.colorBox);
        TextView latText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.latText);
        TextView lngText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.longText);

        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
            float[] values = event.values;
            float x = values[0];
            float y = values[1];
            float z = values[2];

            float acclt = (x*x+ y*y+ z*z)/(SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH*SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
            long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(acclt >2) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Seismic lib: 
https://github.com/square/seismic

Demo app shows how you can use it.